# Calling a optional argument in python using command line interface

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--type', type=str, help='Annuity or Differential')
parser.add_argument('--principal', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--periods', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--interest', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--payment', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

How to call the arguments from the CLI?

**python filename.py --type diff --principal 400000 --periods 8 --interest 3.5 --payment 788888** or **python filename.py --type=diff --principal=400000 --periods=8 --interest=3.5 --payment=788888**

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens?

Comment: the problem is second one works but i watched a tutorial in which they declare a space and according to thar tutorial option 1 should work.. to b precise u have to enter a space after the variable.. thats the option 1 but it doesn't work. its showing error

Comment: You should add your error and what trouble you're having understanding the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--type', type=str, help='Annuity or Differential')
parser.add_argument('--principal', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--periods', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--interest', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--payment', type=int)

#   ===========
parser.add_argument( "files", nargs="*",
                 type=str,
                 help="files to process",
                 default=[])
#   ===========

args = parser.parse_args()
print("args=", args)
```

Results:

```
xxx@xxx:~/tmp$ python3 ./toto.py  --type diff --principal 400000 --periods 8 --interest 3.5 --payment 788888
args= Namespace(files=[], interest=3.5, payment=788888, periods=8, principal=400000, type='diff')

xxx@xxx:~/tmp$ python3 ./toto.py filename.py --type diff --principal 400000 --periods 8 --interest 3.5 --payment 788888
args= Namespace(files=['filename.py'], interest=3.5, payment=788888, periods=8, principal=400000, type='diff')
```